# python crawling to extract review count

Tags: python, web-crawler

i try to make review count crawler using python

```
productURL_path = []
for tag in bsObj.findAll(attrs={'class': 'thumb'}):
    if "href" in tag.attrs:    
        productURL_path.append(tag.get('href'))
for reviewcnt in bsObj.findAll(attrs={'class': 'product-reviews-count'})
```

but i can not get review count 323 between  tag [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIwVV.png)

any idea?

actually since i am not developer, it's gonna be somehow tricky question

plz comment if you need more information to solve this problem.

Comment: Can u share the url you'r trying to scrape.

Comment: https://chaakan.co.kr/product/list.html?cate_no=49

here is url.
this is korea-shoe shopping commerce though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this? I am not too sure what exactly you're trying to do (this is untested)

```py
for reviewcnt in bsObj.findAll(attrs={'class': 'product-reviews-count'}):
    print(reviewcnt.find("b").text)  # 323
```

Comment: [i can get a result ... ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfKkx.png

Comment: @JaehyunLee I just looked into the website and I think it may use JavaScript to render the review count.. So you can't use `requests` or whatever you are using to get the webpage HTML. Maybe try [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)? Best of luck!